# When do we fill in parameters for Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

Self-learning Android at the moment.

My question is when do I need to use the parameters for the instantiating an `Intent`?

Sometimes I write this:

```
Intent baseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, googleURI);
```

Other times:

```
Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(this, ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class);
```

And there are even times such as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

When do I fill in the parameters for the constructor?

And what kind of parameters?

**EDIT**

I want to be clear.

When I say "when", I do not mean when I want to create an empty constructor, I should use `new Intent()`;

I know that `new Intent()` leads to empty constructor. What I meant is under what circumstances do I want to use an empty constructor and therefore use `new Intent();`?

Comment: did you read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html ? search for constructors

Comment: I did. But I am no clearer. While I am relatively proficient in Web programming, Android concepts are currently foreign to me. Is there an analogy to explain concept of Intent? so I can figure out under what circumstances I can use the various kinds of Intent constructor

Answer (score 1):

About intents:

Intents are for exchanging data between components (Activity, Service, Broadcast receiver), but not directly. These components send their intents to the OS, then the OS will forward to the destination component.

An intent contains these elements: *action*, *data*, *component name*, *category*, *extra*, *flags*.

You can build a new intent from a combination of these.

---

If you want to launch a new activity, then simply just create an intent with your **explicit** component name (class) (you can put extra to this intent if you would like to give some data to that activity).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

You can sign up for system events (like boot completed, battery low, incoming call etc.) with a broadcast receiver. When something happens you will get an intent, which contains an ACTION, based on this action you can decide which event is going on. (ex. Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)

You can also create own actions, and send broadcasts to yourself.

```
Intent in = new Intent("SOMEACTION");
sendBroadcast(in);
```

---

*Implicit intents.*

If you left empty the component part of the intent, the the OS will search a right app which can handle this.
Example:

If you would like to call someone, then you need to add your desired action, with your data (tel number) and you leave empty the component parameter.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: So what you are saying is: if i leave out the component name in the parameters, then I am basically creating an implicit Intent. If I do include, then it is explicit intent. Correct?

Comment: About the differences between explicit and implicit, yes. That is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

1.`Intent()`, Create an empty intent

```
public Intent() {
}
```

2.`Intent(Intent o)`, Copy constructor

```
public Intent(Intent o) {
    this.mAction = o.mAction;
    ....
}
```

3.`Intent(String action)`, Create an intent with a given action

```
public Intent(String action) {
    setAction(action);
}
```

4.`Intent(String action, Uri uri)`, Create an intent with a given action and for a given data url

```
public Intent(String action, Uri uri) {
    setAction(action);
    mData = uri;
}
```

5.`Intent(Context context, Class<?> cls)`, Create an intent for a specific component

```
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
}
```

6.`Intent(String action, Uri uri, Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`, Create an intent for a specific component with a specified action and data

```
public Intent(String action, Uri uri,
        Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    setAction(action);
    mData = uri;
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
}
```

**And all the parameters have `get`&`set` methods**, so for example:

```
Intent baseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, googleURI);
```

equals

```
Intent baseIntent = new Intent();
baseIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
baseIntent.setData(googleURI);
```

And

```
Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(this, ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class);
```

equals

```
Intent explicitIntent = new Intent();
explicitIntent.setComponent(new Component(this, ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: no. 6 helps. The rest not so much.

When I say "when", I do not mean when I want to create an empty constructor, I should use new Intent();

I know that new Intent() leads to empty constructor. What I meant is under what circumstances do I want to use an empty constructor and therefore use new Intent();?

Answer (score 0):

The main thing of Intent is ACTION (and may be CATEGORY), that also is the reason to init an Intent (You can see the details of an IntentFilter from Manifest, that definitely show the purpose of an Intent)
Ex: create Intent to start activity manually, or start activity from installed apps, ...

Not much reason to create an Intent via empty constructor (I often create via empty constructor, then use SET method to add action, category, bundle data, ...). When no action for this Intent, the purpose of intent become not very clear. For example: when setResult() in Activity, you can put back an Intent with bundle data, dont need to put an action for that Intent.

Comment: What does ACTION entail? What about CATEGORY? Differences between ACTION and CATEGORY?